# Is it possible to hike the moors in Dartmoor without having a car?

Tags: uk, hiking

I'm interested in doing some hikes in Dartmoor -- single day hikes, for the most part, to see the moors and tors and the like. However I do not have a car, nor am I able to rent one (I have no driver's licence.)

Most of the people I've talked to have told me about hikes, but they all seem to involve first getting to a somewhat remote carpark and going from there. Are there any hikes of moderate difficulty accessible by public transit, or that start within reasonable walking distance from a town? Or are the only options expensive "guided" hikes?

(If the answer varies seasonally, the target season is now: mid-to-late summer starting from mid-July.)

Comment: Bus routes go all through the Dartmoor Forest.   Each route is not necessarily every day, but with planning you can get to and from almost anywhere.

Comment: I have not hiked on Dartmoor, but I have hiked on Exmoor, by signing up to a short holiday where the company supplied the place to stay, a small bus to start and again to collect us at the end of the walk, and a guide/driver who set us on the walk and met us at the end of the day. As a whole it was not expensive.

Comment: Or maybe go by bicycle to the start of the walk? Or try hitchhiking.

Comment: Have you thought about joining a local ramblers group for one of their walks? Not sure but I bet they either start from an easy to reach point or transport their members somehow.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there are a number of bus services that cross or pass into Dartmoor, including the "Haytor Hoppa" (bus service 271) which appears to be designed for the purpose - it's [website](https://www.dartmoor.gov.uk/enjoy-dartmoor/planning-your-visit/travel-information/haytor-hoppa) includes a number of self-guided walks going to and from bus stops.

Answer (score 4):

As well as the bus services there is also now an hourly train service that takes ~39 minutes to Okehampton station which is at the northern edge of Dartmoor. From the station it's about a 10 minute walk over the A30 bridge and you are in Dartmoor. From there there are many excellent hikes. If you're up for wild camping you can walk to very remote areas of the moor. Or stick to circular routes. The last service back to Exeter is 21:15 (varies slightly at weekends) so plenty of time to get back after your walk.

[Hiking around Okehampton - 15 walks](https://www.komoot.com/guide/791540/hiking-around-okehampton)